# get child from json object python?

Tags: python, json

I want to extract the json child from json object, but my code is not working well. Please see the json data below.

**json_main**

```
   {
     "Xpert2FLS": {
       "Application": {
         "Number": "7428-0000",
         "worknumber": null,
         "rowmaterial": {
           "materialnumber": "ROHR B11 LG 546",
           "materialpieces": "2750.00",
           "load": [
               {
                "load-ID": "123",
                "Charge": "83",
                "Lager": "01",
                "place": null,
                "packetnumber": "2548"
               }
            ]
         },
         "Workmaterial": [
            {
             "Arbeitsgangnummer": "50",
             "date1": "15032021",
             "date2": "15032021",
             "machinenumber": "02",
             "resttime": "0"
             }
           ]
        }
       }
     }
```

**my expected json 7 outcome**

```
           {
              "load-ID": "123",
              "Charge": "83",
              "Lager": "01",
              "place": null,
              "packetnumber": "2548"
           }
```

**python**

```
        import pprint
        import json

      with open("auftraege.json", "w") as json_file:
       json_file.write(json_data)
      json_file.close()

      # extract
      for x in json_data['Xpert2FLS']['Application']['rowmaterial']['load']:
        json_data['Xpert2FLS']['Application']['rowmaterial']['load']
```

I am getting type error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: what are you trying to do with the line `json_data['Xpert2FLS']['Application']['rowmaterial']['load']` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: `json_data` is apparently just a string.  You have no access to the objects described by it until you do `json.loads()` on that string.

Comment: also, if the data is in the json file, you need to open the file in read mode to open it and read it, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur support I need to load json. I am uploading code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me I have changed the code.

```
    import json

  # read json data
  # read adding json data
  with open('auftraege.json') as f:
     jsondata = json.load(f)
  # extract   Lademittel
 load_json = json_data['Xpert2FLS']['Application']['rowmaterial']['load']
 with open('outcome.json', 'w') as outfile:
 json.dump(load_json, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```